# Let $(m-1)x-2my+3=0$ where $m$ is a number, prove that for any line $D_m$, $D_m$ passes through the point $(3,3/2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(m-1)x-2my+3=0$ where $m$ is a number, (haha like brian greene higgs boson video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWj00MCqSxs&feature=youtu.be minute 2:22) prove that for any line $D_m$, $D_m$ passes through the point $(3,3/2)$

so i proved that $y=3/2m+x/2+x/(2m)$

Then to prove that i showed that if x=3 then: $y=3/2m+3/2+3/2.1/m$

Therefore:(like nick harvey videos) $y=3/2(m+1+1/m)$

then i can't so please help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT :

Show that 
$$(m-1)\times 3-2m\times \frac{3}{2}+3=0$$
holds for any $m$. (it is obvious though..)

**Note** : $m$ may be $0$, so you can't divide it by $m$. Also, you don't need to simplify it like $y=ax+b.$

Comment: but why what you say is right????? where did you get that equation

Comment: I just set $(x,y)=(3,3/2)$ in the left hand side of your equation. Then, if the left hand side get to $0$, this means the point $(x,y)=(3,3/2)$ is on the line.

Comment: " Then, if the left hand side get to 0, this means the point (x,y)=(3,3/2) is on the line." But why?

Comment: Is it a property or what?

Comment: For example, if you have $y=x+1$, then do you think a point $(1,2)$ is on the line?

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhh okay... but then i have to write (m−1)x−2my+3=0 as y=...

Comment: You got it! but again you don't need to write in the form. I mean $y=x+1$ is the same as $y-x-1=0$. Both represent a line. Also, if you try to change its form to $y=...$, you'll divide the both sides by $m$. But you cannot do this because $m$ may be $0$. That's why I'm saying that you just keep its form and set $(x,y)=(3,3/2)$ in the left hand side.

Comment: ahaaa!!! many thanks!! :)

Comment: You are so welcome!